# Unable to use child className inside parent className in React CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs

I am unable to use child className inside parent className in React CSS file. Also if there is className in my css file then also I am not able to style h3 tag. And I am also not able to use '&' in React CSS file.
Can you please tell me what is problem with below style in React.

```
.info-wrap{
    h3{ // Getting Error
        color: $black;
        position: relative;
        &:after{ // Getting Error
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 60px;
            height: 3px;
            background: $primary;
            content: '';
        }
    }
    .dbox{ // getting error
        width: 100%;
        // color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        &:last-child(){
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        p{
            margin-bottom: 0;
            span{
                font-weight: 400;
                color: $black;
            }
            a{
                color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            }
        }
        .icon{ // getting error
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            span{
                font-size: 20px;
                color: $black;
            }
        }
        .text{ getting error
            width: calc(100% - 50px);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the css file into scss and import $black and $primary.

Comment: Using variables, nesting the styles etc cannot be used in css, those are properties of scss

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.scss` instead of `.css` format for your styling files because using child className inside parent className is not supported in pure css .